# Recursion is not working properly and getting out of function without executing definition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function named as `Check_Reviewed(Form)` and I have a `div` as confirm box. I am showing and hiding this in this function and then calling this function again. But on call, it goes to the last parenthesis of the function and doesn't execute the complete function(as shown by the debugger and experienced). I am unable to understand this behaviour.

The code snippet is as below:

In HTML file I have a div with id `createdConfirmBox` with `display` `hidden`.

**The JS functions:**

```
function hideBox(boxName){
    $("#"+boxName).hide();
    $("bl").hide();
}
function createConfirmBox(name){
    var confirmBox = $("#createdConfirmBox");
    var content = "<div   id='cross_createdConfirmBox_"+name+"' class='cross'>X</div><span id='spanCreatedConfirmBox_"+name+"' style='text-align:center; font-size:18px; line-height:25px; width:580px; padding:7px; font-style:italic; background-color:white; display:inline-block; border-radius:10px;'></span><br><br><div style='text-align:center;' id='divCreatedConfirmBox_"+name+"'></div><br><div style='text-align:center;'><button class='btn btn-primary' type='button'   id='btn_createdConfirmBox_yes_"+name+"' style='padding:5px 25px; margin-right:40px; font-size:18px;' >YES</button><button class='btn btn-cancel' type='button'   style=' padding:5px 25px; font-size:18px; margin-left:40px;' id='btn_createdConfirmBox_no_"+name+"'>NO</button></div><br>";
    confirmBox.html(content);
}

function Check_review(Form){
...
...
...
var company_new = $("#company").val().trim();
        if(company_old && company_old!="" && company_new==""){
            createConfirmBox("company");
            $("#createdConfirmBox").attr("box-made-for","company");
            $("#spanCreatedConfirmBox_company").html("<label style='color:red;'><b>Warning!!!</b></label><br>You have removed <b>Company Name</b> from Contact Details.<br><br><span style='padding:7px;display:inline-block;'>Existing Company Name: <b>"+company_old+"</b><br>New Company Name: <label style='color:#c8c8c8;'>Removed<label></span>");
            $("#divCreatedConfirmBox_company").html("<label  style='color:#464444;'>Do you want to continue without <b>Company Name?</b></label>");
            $("#btn_createdConfirmBox_yes_company").on('click',function(){
                company_old="";
                $("#company").val("");
                hideBox("createdConfirmBox");
                 Check_Reviewed(Form);
            });
            $("#btn_createdConfirmBox_no_company").on('click',function(){
                $("#company").val(company_old);
                hideBox("createdConfirmBox");
                 Check_Reviewed(Form);
            });
            $("#cross_createdConfirmBox_company").on('click',function(){
                $("#company").val(company_old);
                hideBox("createdConfirmBox");
                 Check_Reviewed(Form);
            });
            $("#createdConfirmBox").show();
            $("#bl").show();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

So as I said on click of button `btn_createdConfirmBox_no_company`  it goes to the function defined on click of it. When it comes to line `Check_Reviewed(Form);` it goes to Last line of function `}` without executing code in it. Yhen goes to the last line of click function `});` and then exit.

I am unable to understand this behaviour.

> If you have any other method by which I can do my work then explain as I want to call this function `Check_Reviewd(Form);` on click of any button without making `Form` global variable.

Comment: When you click a button you dont proceed, you just add new listeners again.

Comment: But all other things written in it are done except the `Check_Review();`

Comment: if `$("#company").val()` return undefined, `$("#company").val().trim()` throws an exception and the code stops here.

Comment: But console is showing nothing like error

Comment: `#company` is an textbox it will be empty or with value and is present always on page and in DOM too. So how can it be undefined? And it's being executed rightly because in first attempt the whole code is executed. I added breakpoints on every line to check.

Comment: Surround your code inside your function with a `try...catch` and check if no error happens

Comment: Okay, I'll try. But as I said console is clear and I have added breakpoints before this line too, the also didn't get executed on click.

Comment: Could you post all the code does'nt executed more the line just before?

Comment: I checked again the execution goes to the first line of function but middle code is not executed it goes to last line after that. Might there be exception between these lines of function? If yes then why didn't it catch on first time of execution?

Comment: @Fefux sorry buddy, code is too long, It'll be marked as too long to answer.

Comment: Where `company_old` is defined? If your code is too long, you can create a codepen or a jsfiddle

Comment: It's defined globally in another method in a different js file. Is it the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was in the code written above it in the function. It's getting it outside the function by using return false. I used breakpoints to reach this. The reason was that it was making the checkbox disable on the success of an ajax request which was fired whenever the city name changes and due to this disable checkbox, I was always getting out of the function before completing it.

> I know it was a very silly mistake and lack of knowledge. Thank you, everyone, for their responses and valuable time.